# iOS app that alerts user when approaching specified POI

Tags: ios, maps

I am looking for an iOS app that serves as a geo-location service.  What is needs to do is I enter a location (preferably latitude/longitude coordinates) and the app will sit in the background and wait until I am within a certain distance of the destination e.g. 200 meters.  This alert would be in the form of ideally a vibration, but a visual pop-up alert would also be acceptable.  I am not particularly interested in it showing a visual map, but if it does that's just a bonus!

Requirements:

(Essential Features)

- Is able to run in the background i.e. I can be using another app or have the iPhone locked and it will still run
- It does not drain the battery life substantially i.e. uses AGPS rather than the GPS
- I am able to enter my destination and it will alert me when approaching that destination
- Does not require an internet connection
- Is an iOS app (preferably cross platform, but not essential) able to run on iOS 8
- Has the ability to save POIs for access later on

(Desirable features)

- App is free (but prices up to $3 AUD are acceptable)

Comment: In the meantime I can simply use the default Reminders app in iOS 8 as that provides location based reminders, but an actual app would be nice!

Comment: Where is the difference between the default Reminders app in iOS 8 and another app? Even the default one seems to meet most/all of your requirements?

Comment: @Trilarion; AFAIK the default Reminders app does not have the provision for longitude/latitude input